# How to remove the margin of the first item on the listview?

Tags: css, html, listview, jquery-mobile

I use Jquery mobile with this listview. I can't get rid of the margin on the first item.

[image]

here's my html code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-icon="false"> 
                <a href="#meals"><img src="images/meal.jpg" alt="meal" /><h2>Meals</h2><p>Enjoy the sweet Tinulang Barbeque ni Mang Juan for $99.</p></a> 
            </li>
            <li data-icon="false">
                <a href="#desserts"><img src="images/desserts.jpg" alt="dessert"/><h2>Desserts</h2><p>Taste the Sea of Pier 3 with Condensed milk for $11.</p></a> 
            </li>
            <li data-icon="false">
                <a href="#beverages"><img src="images/beverages.jpg" alt="beverage"/><h2>Beverages</h2><p>Drink the Water of Pandora with Amonium Nitrate for $25.</p></a> 
            </li>
</ul>
```

I tried this css code but still the same:

```
.listitem {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}

#list{
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}

#list .ui-li {
    border: none;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: `:first-child` selector http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/

Comment: There's no problem on other browser, it only appears on ice cream sandwich devices.

Answer (score 0):

Check by applying inline `style="margin:0 !important"` if it still not solve your problem then check in inspect element if there is padding or margin

Answer (score 0):

The margin above the first item is actually the top margin on the UL element. So assuming #list is your UL, just add `margin-top: 0;`:

```
#list{
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/xm9cvr8a/)**